# Do I have to run SKSE to launch Skyrim every time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I downloaded SKSE (Skyrim Script Extender) and started Skyrim the normal way but I got popups that SKSE was not working properly. I then ran SKSE and it worked properly. But the question is do I really have to run this every time I play?

Comment: But what if I start the normal Skyrim? Will it change anything or will SKSE not work again? @NoneOfYourBusiness

Comment: This has already been answered, but I'd like to note why: installing SKSE does not alter any files in your Skyrim installation. Instead it adds a new program (SKSE.exe) that when you launch it starts Skyrim and extends the functionality of the scripts. This is not permanent, it's just for as long as skyrim is running. So you have to start it with SKSE.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you do not have any mods that rely on SKSE, you should be fine. However, if you have mods like SkyUI, those will get pretty upset, and will not work/cause crash =/

Comment: Heh, beaten to it by seconds :)

Answer (score 6):

SKSE is required for some 3rd party mods to function. It will usually indicate on the mod's download page whether SKSE is required (at least on sites like Nexus.)

If you're happy to play Skyrim without your 3rd party mods, or with those mods potentially not working properly, you can run the standard executable and the game will work. SKSE will not be affected if you do this.

However, if you want to play with your 3rd party mods, you will need to continue running SKSE as your method of launching Skyrim.